# Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly

I am getting a weird error after switching to Wildfly 8 from JBoss 7.  The error is "Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo".

In a REST handler, I am passing a UriInfo object to an asynchronous call.  In JBoss 7 this worked fine.  After switching to Wildfly I get the following error:

```
2014-05-14 11:47:08,938 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 3) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component MeasurementStreamQueryAsync for method public void org.neoninc.cds.pdr.rest.MeasurementStreamQueryAsync.createQueryResults(org.neoninc.cds.domain.CdsQuery,java.lang.String,java.util.Date,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo): javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:439) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:79) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$1.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:87) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo
                at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:54) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.getRequestUri(Unknown Source)
                at org.neoninc.cds.pdr.rest.MeasurementStreamQueryAsync.generateStructuredFileFromResults(MeasurementStreamQueryAsync.java:523) [classes:]
                at org.neoninc.cds.pdr.rest.MeasurementStreamQueryAsync.generateFileForDataProduct(MeasurementStreamQueryAsync.java:294) [classes:]
                at org.neoninc.cds.pdr.rest.MeasurementStreamQueryAsync.createQueryResults(MeasurementStreamQueryAsync.java:186) [classes:]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
                at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                ... 38 more
```

I am using Wildfly 8.0.0-2.Final.

The asynchronous call is simply a method in another stateless bean with the method annotated as @Asynchronous.

Did something change about UriInfo, or can someone point me to the root cause of the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: So as a workaround for anyone looking, I ended up refactoring the code to pass a UriBuilder created from the UriInfo object.  Then I could guarantee the object's existence.  From what I can tell, the UriInfo object now throws an exception when used outside of the scope of the request (in this case an asynchronous method).

Comment: You might as well make that an answer to close the question. That is the only solution. The `UriInfo` needs to be accessed from inside a request scope/context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why things changed in the new version of Wildfly, but it looks like the only solution is to refactor things as I described in the workaround.

> Blockquote
>   So as a workaround for anyone looking, I ended up refactoring the code to pass a UriBuilder created from the UriInfo object. Then I could guarantee the object's existence. From what I can tell, the UriInfo object now throws an exception when used outside of the scope of the request (in this case an asynchronous method).

Comment: For more information, see http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#asyncContextNote